# TomTom reverse Geocode not returning street name for some gps coordinates

Tags: tomtom

For some GPS coordinates, no street name is returned. For example

```
https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/reverseGeocode/47.532289,-122.251843.json?key=MYKEY&roadUse=[%22LocalStreet%22]&returnRoadUse=true
```

returns

```
{"summary":{"queryTime":102,"numResults":1},"addresses":[{"address":{"routeNumbers":[],"countryCode":"US","countrySubdivision":"WA","countrySecondarySubdivision":"King","countryTertiarySubdivision":"Seattle East","municipality":"Mercer Island","postalCode":"98040","municipalitySubdivision":"Mercer Island","country":"United States","countryCodeISO3":"USA","freeformAddress":"Mercer Island, WA 98040","boundingBox":{"northEast":"47.535094,-122.241410","southWest":"47.534766,-122.242287","entity":"position"},"countrySubdivisionName":"Washington"},"position":"47.534897,-122.242287","roadUse":["Publicly Accessible","LocalStreet","Terminal"]}]}
```

Which contains no street name. Is there anyway to tell the TomTom API to return results that ALWAYS include a street name?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a hack, but if we create a pedestrian route starting with that location (in the middle of Lake Washington) the first instruction starts usually at the closest street that can be navigable, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

These coordinates are pointing to a lake. And the nearest road is some living street with no name. So that is not a perfect example.

Comment: There is no way to tell the API to return the closest street name?

Comment: So are you expecting that this API is returning something like "unnamed road"?

Comment: That is not feasible